# Function declaration of ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Suppose we have a function using ES6 syntax like this:

```
const AccountOverview = (props) => {
  const overviewVisible = props.overviewVisible;
  const accountNumber = props.accountNumber;
  const toggleAccountOverview = props.toggleAccountOverview;

  const onClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    toggleAccountOverview(!overviewVisible, accountNumber);
  };
  // FIXME: eslint WHY??????
  /* eslint-disable */
  return (
    <div
      className={props.overviewVisible ? 'acc-block open' : 'acc-block'}
    >
        <div>
)
}
```

and a function like this:

```
const AccountDetails = props => (
  <div className="tabInner">
          </div>
)
```

Why the first function is declared using {} and the second function is declared using just ()?

Comment: BTW: Functions are not valid, you need to surround html with backticks

Comment: Read the documentation for arrow functions. Pay attention to the notion of "concise body".

Answer (score 1):

`{}` means the body of the arrow function, which can contain **multiple statements**. In this case you need to use `return` explicitly to return data from your function.

Without `{}`, your arrow function must have a **single statement body** which result will be returned implicitly without `return` statement.

The `()` is in that situations where you need to return an object within single statement body. Like

```
const getObject = () => ({ name: 'Test' });
```

Without `()` it will consider `{}` of the object the function body and give you an error.

Comment: Probably because you should've closed this as a duplicate, instead of answering.

Comment: Probably because this information is already front and center in every single explanation of arrow functions in the world. Plus, it's wrong. The form without `{}` does not take a "single statement body"; it takes an **expression**. If you do choose to regurgitate such readily available information as an "answer", then in addition to making sure it's correct, at a minimum introduce the proper terminology, which in this case is "concise body form". And provide links to documentation and further information.

Comment: it's a good and short answer for using arrow functions without `return`.